# Group the first character in a string by any of the characters in another string

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

In Linq2Sql given a list of string, I need a query that returns back all the strings that has a system that starts with any of the characters in the string.

This is what I've come up with: (Needs help with this function)

```
void Main()
{
    var strings = new List<string>(){"ABCDE", "FGHIJ", "KLMNO"};
    var values = GetUsedStrings(strings);
    /*
     * In my case expected to return strings "ABCDE" and "KLMNO" 
     * since there exists Systems that starts
     * with any of the characters in those strings.
     */
    values.Dump();
}

public IList<string> GetUsedStrings(IList<string> strings)
{
    var q = from s in tblSystems
            where s.systemName != null && s.systemName.Length > 0
            group s by s.systemName[0] into g //Somehow need to group by the characters strings list?
            select g.Key;

    return q.ToList();
}
```

A single string check would be: (works as expected)

```
private bool StartsWithAny(string characters)
{
    return
        (from s in tblSystems
        where 
          s.systemName != null && s.systemName.Length > 0 &&
          characters.Contains(s.systemName[0])
        select s).Any();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    private bool StartsWithAny(string characters)
    {
         string aa = @"if exists(select * from tblSystems where  
                    systemName is not null and LEN(systemName)>0";

         for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
         {
             aa += " and SUBSTRING([login],1,1) = '" + characters[i] + "'";
         }
         aa+=")";
         return db.ExecuteQuery<bool>(aa).Single();
    }
```

Comment: The `GetUsedStrings` function in my question is the one Im having trubble with. `StartsWithAny?`  works as expected

Answer (score -1):

Would it solve your problem if you would build a new string from the List what you get, but that wouldn't give you groups that's true.